# Define style in javascript with qTip2?

Tags: jquery, tooltip, qtip, qtip2

In qTip1 you could easily style every single tooltip at runtime, but since qTip2 you can 'only' pass a CSS class to apply to the tooltip.

So ok this is cleaner, but is there still a way I can change the style (or at least the color) of a tooltip **at runtime** ?

I guess adding a `<style>` block in my rendered view defining a class and then using that class could work but I'd prefer a pure javascript way of doing it.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change easily the class *(and with this **every** style)* at runtime with:

```
$("#tip").qtip('option', 'style.classes', 'class-you-want');
```

SEE my **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/neysor/WRRaB/)** (It changes the tooltip style at runtime)

#### RESULT

[image]

#### HTML

```
<a href="#" id="tip">Tooltip for that</a><br>
<a href="#" id="r">RED</a> - <a href="#" id="b">BLUE</a>​
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $("#tip").qtip({
    content: {
        text: "Test"
        }});
    $("#r").click(function() {
        $("#tip").qtip('option', 'style.classes', 'ui-tooltip-red');
    });
    $("#b").click(function() {
        $("#tip").qtip('option', 'style.classes', 'ui-tooltip-blue');
    });
});​
```

You can read more in the **[Documentation](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/api/#properties)**

Comment: Actually I was looking for a pure JS way, without relying on a css class ... But it's been a while now so I ended up using a CSS class anyway. Therefore I accept the answer for it explains well how to make just that.

Also +1 for your answer because I didn't know about that option/style.classes syntax !

Comment: Y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶d̶e̶m̶o̶ ̶d̶o̶e̶s̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶ ̶a̶n̶y̶m̶o̶r̶e̶ ̶:̶C̶ 
actually it does when changing classes to `qtip-red` and `-blue` respectively. Dammit, so there really must be a bug in my code =_=